# express-recaptcha : ReferenceError: config is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
  recaptchaConfig() {
        this.recaptcha = new Recaptcha(
            config.service.recaptcha.client_key,
            config.service.recaptcha.secret_key , 
            {...config.service.recaptcha.options}
        );
    }
```

I tested this code but it gives me this error: ReferenceError: config is not defined

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I advise you to read the how to ask a good question (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: OK, so `config` isn't defined. There's no sign of any attempt to define it in  your code, so ‍♂️. What did you expect?